# Two week notice if my boss doesn't seem to care?

Tags: quitting, notice-period

I've been working as a contractor at a very large company. They seem to be very inefficient with their hourly employees; my boss hasn't spoken to me for the past 5 months. At the start, I had to approach him to get any kind of work to do or feedback on my performance; there is no proactive oversight. The full time employees seem too busy to help new people, or give feedback, or even make sure we're working. Perhaps the company makes so much money that overseeing contractors isn't an efficient use of time.

In any case, I'm seeking other employment and I'm wondering whether to give any notice at all. Nobody I "report" to has ever even asked to see my work. I don't have any work-handoff reasons to stay two weeks beyond putting in a resignation, but I don't want to burn a bridge with my employer by abruptly leaving.

Comment: If you're a contractor, that implies you have a contract.  The contract would definitely include how much notice you have to provide.

Answer (score 8):

First step is to check your contract. Does it require a notice? If so, follow what it says.

If not, still put in the standard (assuming US) 2 weeks notice. It is the right thing to do. It shows to the company that you are professional, which could be to your advantage some day. It also shows to your new employer that you will be respectful to them if you ever leave them. There is little to nothing to gain by not doing it.

Comment: Also: If you leave without notice, you may sacrifice the ability to use this employer as a reference.

Comment: "*There is little to nothing to gain by not doing it.*" And at the risk of stating the obvious: you have a lot to lose by not respecting industry standard notice periods.